# PyPI missing files on package install?

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

I'm trying to create a PyPI package but when I install it locally using `pip install -e .` the code works fine, but when I install it after create the package using `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` and I install it `pip install {file_location}` I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tutorials-backup", line 5, in <module>
    from down import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'down'
```

My file structure is:

```
root
  |- config.py
  |- down.py
  |- LICENSE
  |- MANIFEST.in
  |- progress.py
  |- README.md
  |- setup.py
  |- tutorials.py
```

my setup.py file looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Package metadata
....

# Package dependencies
install_requires = [
    'requests',
    'tqdm',
    'telethon',
    'python-slugify',
    'ffmpeg-python',
]

# Setup configuration
setup(
    name=name,
    version=version,
    author=author,
    author_email=author_email,
    description=description,
    long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license=license,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={"": ["*.py"]},
    install_requires=install_requires,
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [ 'tutorials-backup = down:main'],
    },
)
```

My down.py (the startup point file) looks like this:

```
import os
import argparse
from skillshare import Downloader

def configure():
    # Code that works as an installer for some variables

def main():
    ........
    # all the code inside main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I really don't know what's happening or what's creating that `from down import main` or where it's making that, anybody can help me or know what's happening? it's my first time trying to make a PyPI package.

Comment: Follow tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ -- Pay close attention to project directory structure. -- Do you really want `down` (and `config` and `progress`) to be top level imports? That is quite unusual and against community practices. Typically you would have only one top-level import (an import package), and the modules inside that package. For example `from my_package import down`.